# Laravel use non-laravel composer package in controller

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, laravel-5

I'm trying to use a non-laravel composer package in a Laravel controller. I've added the project to the composer.json file like so:

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "abraham/twitteroauth": "0.5.2"
},
```

I then ran:

```
composer update
```

Within the project, which has installed the package in the vendor/ directory as expected, and I see it there. However, when adding the following code to the controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class HomeController extends Controller {

    use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

public function index()
{
    $o = new TwitterOauth();
    return view('home');
}
```

Laravel returns the following error:

> Trait 'App\Http\Controllers\Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth' not found

I suspect this has something to do with the fact that the namespace is already declared, but I don't know enough about PHP namespaces to resolve the issue.

Any help would be welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your controller file is in the `App\Http\Controllers` namespace

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

You attempted to add a trait to your controller using a relative class/trait name

```
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;
```

If you use a relative trait name, PHP will assume you want trait **in the current namespace**, which is why it complains about

```
App\Http\Controllers\Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth
```

or

```
App\Http\Controllers\
combined with
Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth
```

Try using an absolute trait name, and you should be fine

```
use \Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;
```

Or, import the `TwitterOAuth` into the current namespace

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;
```

And then use with the short name

```
class HomeController extends Controller {

    use TwitterOAuth;
}
```

**Update**:

OK, we get to blame PHP's double use of `use` here.  In  your class definition, you said

```
class HomeController extends Controller {

    use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

    public function index()
    {
        $o = new TwitterOauth();
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

When you use `use` inside a class, PHP interprets that as "apply this trait to this class".  I'm not familiar with the library, so I assumed that `Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth` is a trait.  It's not.

When you use `use` **outside** of a class definition, you're telling PHP to to "use this class in this namespace without a namespace prefix".  If you remove the `use` statement from your class

```
class HomeController extends Controller {

    //use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;
}
```

and place it outside, under the `namespace` keyword

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;
```

You should be able to use the class `TwitterOAuth` to instantiate your objects.

Comment: When using the absolute name, I receive the error: Trait 'Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth' not found. Is there a step I've missed out somewhere?

Comment: @BnMcG OK, so at least its complaining about the correct class now.  That error makes it sound like PHP tries to autoload Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth, but finds no class.  Running "composer dumpautoload" might fix that, but that should have happened automatically when you ran "composer update".  Is Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth listed in vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php?

Comment: I ran the composer update command on the VM after running it on my local machine and then uploading, and the error changed to: "App\Http\Controllers\HomeController cannot use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth - it is not a trait"... autoload_psr4.php contains the following line: "'Abraham\\TwitterOAuth\\' => array($vendorDir . '/abraham/twitteroauth/src')," so I guess it's listed there correctly.

Comment: That's fixed it! Thanks very much & thanks for the lesson on namespaces!